# Unable to apply Reduce to a variable number of inequalities (obtained by InputFields)

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate, inequalities, algorithm

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm stuck on this piece of code.
The code is supposed to let the user choose how many inequalities (in a number between 1 and 5) they want to be evaluated.

```
Manipulate[Column[{Table[
With[{index = i}, InputField[Dynamic[var[index]], String, ContinuousAction -> True, FieldHint -> "Field " <> ToString[index]]], {i, n}]
}], {{n, 2}, 2, 5, 1}, Initialization :> (var[_] = "";)]
```

So far so good, the code seems to what we need: it varies automatically the number of InputFields.
The next step I need is to automatically evaluate each single inequality quand print their solution as an output by using the *Reduce* function. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Clear[var]
Manipulate[
 Column[{Table[
    With[{index = i}, 
     if[index] = 
      InputField[Dynamic[var[index]], String, 
       ContinuousAction -> True, 
       FieldHint -> "Field " <> ToString[index]]], {i, n}],
   Button["Evaluate", 
    Do[var[i] = 
      StringJoin[var[i], " = ", ToString[ToExpression[var[i]]]], {i, 
      n}]],
   Button["Clear", Do[var[i] = " ", {i, n}]]
   }]
 , {{n, 2}, 1, 5, 1}, Initialization :> Do[var[i] = " ", {i, n}]]
```

[image]

Then when you give some input and click "Evaluate":

[image]